# Python Command '[ ... ]' returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, google-bigquery, smtp, airflow

I'm trying to get a file from BigQuery, convert it to excel format and sending it attached in an email. Here is my code:

```
def run(**kwargs):
    from datetime import datetime
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    import pandas as pd

    def from_bq_to_dataframe(sql_location):
        client = bigquery.Client()
        with open(sql_location) as file:
            sql = file.read()
        df = client.query(sql).to_dataframe()
        return df

    def filter_and_excel(df):
        df = df.nlargest(1000, ['cant_form_final'])
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Document_name' + '_' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d')) 
        df = df.to_excel(writer, 'review_document') #Sheet name
        return df

    def send_mail(subject, text, send_to, send_to_cc=[], file=None):
        import smtplib
        from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

        username = "user@gmail.com"
        password = "*****"

        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = username
        msg['To'] = ', '.join(send_to)
        msg['Cc'] = ', '.join(send_to_cc)
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg.attach(file)

        server = smtplib.SMTP(host="host_address", port=587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username, password)

        server.sendmail(username, send_to, msg.as_string())
        server.quit()

    subject = 'review ' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    text = 'Hi,\n\n' \
           'I attach the review.\n\n' 

    send_mail(subject=subject,
              text=text,
              send_to=['mail@gmail.com'],
              send_to_cc=['mail1@gmail.com'],
              file=[filter_and_excel(from_bq_to_dataframe(**kwargs))]
              )
```

When I try it locally I have no problems, but when I try linking it to big query I get this error:

```
Exception:
Command '['/tmp/venvq6e8hcce/bin/python', '/tmp/venvq6e8hcce/script.py', '/tmp/venvq6e8hcce/script.in', '/tmp/venvq6e8hcce/script.out', '/tmp/venvq6e8hcce/string_args.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Does anyone know why is that error happening? What does it mean?
Every similar error I found comes from installing python itself or maybe pip. Maybe I have some problem with the python version? I'm using 3.8

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: in your code use `print()` or  `logging` to see which part of code is executed and what you have variables.

Comment: Try updating the [modules](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html).